# Binding Azure EasyTable data to ListView in Windows interface

Tags: c#, wpf, azure

As the title states, I am trying to bind data from an Azure "EasyTable" to an interface in a UWP app. When debugging, I seem to just get a path for the items in the table? [This is what is output during debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7wEz.png) Only 1 entry is being bound to "items" and this is obviously what is displayed in the output from above.. Not sure how to pull actual entries from the table in Azure. The table name is "Event" and the app is connected to the database just fine. I have been trying to follow [This guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/#filtering) in the Azure documentation, but with no success.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

C# Code:

```
    IMobileServiceTable<Event> eventTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<Event>();
    IMobileServiceTable untypedEventTable = App.MobileService.GetTable("events");
    // MobileServiceCollection<Event, Event> items;

    public class Event
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public bool deleted { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }



    private async Task RefreshEvents()
    {
        MobileServiceInvalidOperationException exception = null;
        try
        {
            List<Event> items = await eventTable
                .Where(Event => Event.deleted == false)
                .ToListAsync();
            IEnumerable itemsControl = items;


            ListItems.ItemsSource = items;
        }
        catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException e)
        {
            exception = e;
        }

        if (exception != null)
        {
            await new MessageDialog(exception.Message, "Error loading items").ShowAsync();
        }
    }

    private async void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await RefreshEvents();
    }
}
```

XAML Code:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button x:Name="btnRefresh" Content="Refresh Results" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="213,150,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="137" Click="btnRefresh_Click"/>
    <ListView x:Name="ListItems" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="436" Margin="10,194,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="340"/>
</Grid>
```